# how to filter other objects swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

i am on a new project where i should filter other items in this function. in particular I have to filter address and by city

```
public var name: String
public var email: String
public var address: String?
public var shopName: String?
public var city: String?
```

as it stands now, I have to add by address and city again. this work

```
filteredRestaurants = restaurants?.filter{ (($0.shopName ?? $0.name).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) && (($0.getType() == ESERCENTE_TYPE.GDO && gdoOption!) ||
                ($0.getType() == ESERCENTE_TYPE.RISTORANTE && restaurantOption!)) }
```

but if I add this too no

```
$0.address.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
```

Update:

try this but it completely busted the search. it doesn't even filter by name anymore

filteredRestaurants = restaurants?.filter{ (($0.shopName ?? $0.name).lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) && (($0.getType() == ESERCENTE_TYPE.GDO && gdoOption!) ||                                                                                                                                                                                                ($0.getType() == ESERCENTE_TYPE.RISTORANTE && restaurantOption!)) || (($0.address?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())) != nil)

Comment: **but if I add this too no** what does that mean ?

Comment: @Sh_Khan that does not fill me in and gives me an error saying that to insert “?? Default value ”but I don't know what to put in place of Default value

Comment: Maybe you should explain in words what you are trying to achieve and/or an example. Also make sure to include all properties that you are using in your filter code (or remove them from the filter code for clarity) like `getType`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm trying to filter the search for stores. with name if I do a search for store names it filters me out. I must add the possibility of doing the search also by address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is no need to lowercase your search. You can use `localizedStandardContains` method which is diacritic and case insensitive. Second it is much easier to check if each property contains your search and if true just return true for your filter. If none of them succeeds just return false:

```
filteredRestaurants = restaurants.filter { restaurant in
    if restaurant.name.localizedStandardContains(searchText) {
        return true
    }
    if restaurant.shopName?.localizedStandardContains(searchText) == true {
        return true
    }
    if restaurant.address?.localizedStandardContains(searchText) == true {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: not work..in this way whatever I write the research does not change